# How to access control in DataGridTemplateColumn to get value?

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0

How to access control in DataGridTemplateColumn to get value ?

I'm using this code :

```
  <DataGrid HeadersVisibility="None"  Name="dgUser" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding}"
 CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" CanUserSortColumns="False">
                                <DataGrid.Columns>
                                    <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="*" Header="" IsReadOnly="True">
                                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                            <DataTemplate>
                                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"  Margin="10,0,0,0" Grid.Column="0"  Name="partcount">
                                                    <TextBlock Margin="0,0,5,0" Text="Count"/>
                                                    <TextBox Margin="0,0,5,0" MinWidth="50" Width="Auto" Name="txtcount" Text="{Binding Count}"/>
                                                </StackPanel>
                                            </DataTemplate>
                                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
       </DataGrid.Columns>
                            </DataGrid>
```

how to access txtcount ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to navigate the visual tree to find this element. I wrote a utility class a while back that makes this a little easier, using [Linq-to-VisualTree](http://blog.scottlogic.com/2010/03/04/linq-to-visual-tree.html) you can find it as follows:

```
TextBox tb = dgUser.Descendants<TextBox>()
                   .OfType<TextBox>()
                   .Where(t => t.Name == "txtcount")
                   .Single();
```

Comment: What cell would the TextBox show as result, the one on the first row right ?

Comment: error : Error 1 'System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid' does not contain a definition for 'Descendants' and no extension method 'Descendants' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @user1799345 Descendants() is an extension method that he wrote. follow the link that he provided.

Comment: @ColinE Do you have a new version for `.NET Core`? In `WPF Core`, I'm getting the following error with the exact same DataGrid the `OP` has above: `System.InvalidOperationException
  HResult=0x80131509
  Message=Sequence contains no elements
  Source=System.Linq`