# Accessing DataGridTemplateColumn

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I'm trying to have a path in a datagrid. I wrote the following data template:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding AlertProgram}" IsEnabled="False" Grid.Column="0" />
                <Button Content="..." Grid.Column="1" Click="Button_browse_alert_program" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

(I wrote it straight into the `<DataGrid.columns>` elelment)

In the function `Button_browse_alert_program` I open a OpenFileDialog to get a file.

My problem is - I can't access the text box. I tried giving it a name using `x:Name="someName"` but the compiler complains that the name doesn't exist.

I have seen the following SO questions: [How to access datagrid template column textbox text WPF C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16997951/how-to-access-datagrid-template-column-textbox-text-wpf-c-sharp), [How to access control in DataGridTemplateColumn to get value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13226985/how-to-access-control-in-datagridtemplatecolumn-to-get-value)

Is there a way to do this without third party software, and without writing my own `FindChild` function?

(I'm quite new to WPF, so if you have other comments on my code - speak up)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why would you do all that? Why thrid party software?

Take a look at this:

```
    <DataGrid x:Name="dG">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <TextBox x:Name="tbx">test</TextBox>
                            <Button Content="click me" Grid.Column="1" Click="OnClick" />
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGrid.ItemsSource>
            test
        </DataGrid.ItemsSource>
    </DataGrid>
```

This is code behind:

```
    private void OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox tbx = null;
        // grid is a panel, panels have children
        var parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent((DependencyObject)sender) as Panel;
        foreach(var child in parent.Children)
        {
            if (child is TextBox)
            {
                tbx = (TextBox)child;
                break;
            }
        }

        // you should check if tbx != null
        tbx.Text = "Hello";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Technically you should have some implementation of `ICommand`, bind `Button.Command` to your ViewModel and do what you want in there but if you're fixed on doing it this way then you can access `DataConext` through `sender` in `Button_browse_alert_program`

```
private void Button_browse_alert_program(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   var value = ((sender as Button).DataContext as MyItemClass).AlertProgram;
}
```